# Google Analytics - less than n minutes ago

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

[Google Analytics Realtime](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/) provides `rt:minutesAgo`, on which one could filter queries.

However, it being a dimension and not a metric, `<=` cannot be used in the filter.

Assuming I want to get some numeric metric (like `rt:totalEvents`) for the last *n* minutes, what would be the best way to do this?

---

Currently, the only idea that I have is to create a regex, which matches numbers <= *n*, use `=~` and then sum all `rt:totalEvents` in the result set. This sounds wrong on so many levels.

Comment: Why not just create a function to parse the response to get what you want? The rows object will look something like ["00",7]...["29", 13] where the first element is the minute and the second element is the number of events. Seems like it would be fairly easy to parse this, convert those to integers and return what you want.

Comment: @Pete, to reduce the load/make the response faster for example. You can make the same argument for the filtering functionality in general - post processing can always be done by the client. I don't see why `minutesAgo` isn't numeric in the first place.

Comment: Fair enough. There is no numeric filter for dimensions. You'd have to go regex route or a long combination of filters to get what you want. There is a property in the response that sums it up for you: `totalsForAllResults`

Comment: @Pete, nice one, will use that if I end up going the regex path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, `minutesAgo` is a time dimension and could not be a metric because it could not be aggregated in any inherently *default* way.

Imagine you drilldown by country (dimensions=rt:country)... and there are N visitors from one country that hit your site in the last 10 minutes. What would the value of minutesAgo be? the average? the latest?

Metrics need to be aggregate-able for them to be metrics. Time values in OLAP databases tend not to have this property (inherently), hence they are better modelled as dimensions (usually by periods: "day", "week"... or in this case "minutesAgo").

As mentioned by @Pete, in this case you can still apply a long combination of filters (or a regexp) and use `totalsForAllResults`:

```
"totalsForAllResults": {
  "rt:totalEvents": "2"
 },
```